# Jquery issue when two functions are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Hey guys I am new to web design and making a site for the family business.

Both of these jquery functions work when the other isn't present in the code but when both are used the first (scroll to) fails to work.

Scroll to location function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
        }, 2000);
});
  </script>
```

Scroll to new page on user scroll function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#fullpage').fullpage({
             sectionsColor: ['#7b797a', '#2039cf','#2039cf' ],
             css3: true      
         });
   });
  </script>
```

any advice would be appreciated thanks

Comment: you might want to include the first code block into the `ready` event handler of the second script.

Comment: The HTML of the page would come in handy as placement of the first script block is important (as it is not in a DOM ready handler like the second script).

Answer (score 2):

You should call the first block of code inside of the `$(document).ready();` call in the second block.  Basically you're setting up an event listener (in this case, a button click) on an element (the button) that may not exist yet because the page is still loading.  Setting up the listener inside of `$(document).ready();` makes it wait until the page is loaded.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#7b797a', '#2039cf','#2039cf' ],
            css3: true      
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what you say makes sense however it would seem the issue isn't the document not being ready, I tried entering your code and it seems that caused both scripts to cease functioning (instead of usually only one). Could there be a conflict issue?

Comment: Could the issue be that the fullpage function disables the scrollbar? and if so is there a way to scroll to id without one?

Comment: Its a bit difficult to tell without actually seeing what's going on.  Can you check the developer console to see if you have any errors related to the fullpage plugin?  Are your libraries being loaded properly?  If you're using [This FullPage plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/), its entirely possible that its messing with the scrollbars.

Is the button click code still working?